# Add Info window in Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to ask about how to add an info window to a marker in Google Maps. The condition is, I have to create a program with multiple markers on a map. But how I can give a specified info window to each marker?

This is my code for now:

```js
var markers = [];
    var map;
    var labels = 'ABCD';
    var labelIndex = 0;

    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413),
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
      // New York, NY, USA (40.7127837, -74.0059413)
      // Newark, NJ, USA (40.735657, -74.1723667)
      // Jersey City, NJ, USA (40.72815749999999, -74.07764170000002)
      // Bayonne, NJ, USA (40.6687141, -74.11430910000001)

      addMarker({
        lat: 40.7127837,
        lng: -74.0059413
      }, "red");
      addMarker({
        lat: 40.735657,
        lng: -74.1723667
      }, "green");
      addMarker({
        lat: 40.7281575,
        lng: -74.0776417
      }, "yellow");
      addMarker({
        lat: 40.6687141,
        lng: -74.1143091
      }, "orange");
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);


    function addMarker(location, color) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
        icon: {
          url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/' + color + '.png',
          labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(15, 10)
        },
        map: map
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
```

Can someone give me a solution on how to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
var markers = [];
var map;
var labels = 'ABCD';
var labelIndex = 0;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413),
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  // New York, NY, USA (40.7127837, -74.0059413)
  // Newark, NJ, USA (40.735657, -74.1723667)
  // Jersey City, NJ, USA (40.72815749999999, -74.07764170000002)
  // Bayonne, NJ, USA (40.6687141, -74.11430910000001)

  addMarker({
    lat: 40.7127837,
    lng: -74.0059413
  }, "red", "New York is awesome!");
  addMarker({
    lat: 40.735657,
    lng: -74.1723667
  }, "green", "Newark is also cool!");
  addMarker({
    lat: 40.7281575,
    lng: -74.0776417
  }, "yellow", "Do not forget Jersey City!");
  addMarker({
    lat: 40.6687141,
    lng: -74.1143091
  }, "orange", "And not to mention Bayonne, too!");
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function addMarker(location, color, content) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
    icon: {
      url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/' + color + '.png',
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(15, 10)
    },
    map: map
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  markers.push(marker);
}
```

Comment: ahh oke, then i how i put text to the info window ? ( each marker have different info)

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you can set the text for the info window of each marker. Now it should be clearer. Please mark my answer as correct, if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: Great, happy to hear that :)